# if $F:X\to X$ is continuous, such that for some $\mu>0$, $\left \langle F(u), u \right \rangle\geq 0$ for all $u\in X$ with $||u||=\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

**If $(X,\left \langle \cdot , \cdot   \right \rangle)$ is a Hilbert space of finite dimension and if $F:X\to X$ is continuous, such that for some $\mu>0$, $\left \langle F(u), u \right \rangle\geq 0$ for all $u\in X$ with $||u||=\mu$, then there is $u_0\in X$, $||u_0||\leq\mu$ such that $F(u_0)=0$.**

I know that to solve this problem I have to use Brouwer's fixed point theorem, but I don't know how to use it. Any suggestions? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I would rather go for a retraction $D^n\to S^{n-1}$ for a contradiction: if $F(u)\ne 0$ for all $u\in D^n$, then map $u$ to the unique boundary point of the form $u+tF(u)$ with $t\ge 0$. Use the condition to show it's continuous.

Comment: @Berci 
How can I use the condition to prove that this function is continuous?